# GAE Bulkloader: 'invalid literal for int() with base 10' Error when uploading data

Tags: google-app-engine, bulkloader

I have the following bulkloader created and can successfully download the data.

```
- kind: EmailRegistration
  connector: csv
  connector_options:

  property_map:
    - property: __key__
      external_name: key
      export_transform: transform.key_id_or_name_as_string

    - property: auth_provider
      external_name: auth_provider
      # Type: Key Stats: 6 properties of this type in this kind.
      import_transform: transform.create_foreign_key('AuthProvider', key_is_id=True)
      export_transform: transform.key_id_or_name_as_string

    - property: code
      external_name: code
      # Type: String Stats: 6 properties of this type in this kind.

    - property: email
      external_name: email
      # Type: String Stats: 6 properties of this type in this kind.

    - property: is_user_combined
      external_name: is_user_combined
      # Type: Boolean Stats: 6 properties of this type in this kind.
      import_transform: transform.regexp_bool('true', re.IGNORECASE)

    - property: name
      external_name: name
      # Type: String Stats: 6 properties of this type in this kind.
```

One line of the downloaded csv:

```
code    is_user_combined    name    auth_provider   key email
57H8qSAcvS  True    Mr Sharma   em|xxxx@gmail.com   57H8qSAcvS  xxxx@gmail.com
```

Without changing anything in the data, when I am trying to upload it back, I get the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kave/workspace/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/adaptive_thread_pool.py", line 175, in WorkOnItems
    status, instruction = item.PerformWork(self.__thread_pool)
  File "/home/kave/workspace/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/bulkloader.py", line 767, in PerformWork
    transfer_time = self._TransferItem(thread_pool)
  File "/home/kave/workspace/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/bulkloader.py", line 936, in _TransferItem
    self.content = self.request_manager.EncodeContent(self.rows)
  File "/home/kave/workspace/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/bulkloader.py", line 1416, in EncodeContent
    entity = loader.create_entity(values, key_name=key, parent=parent)
  File "/home/kave/workspace/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/bulkload/bulkloader_config.py", line 456, in create_entity
    entity = self.dict_to_entity(input_dict, self.bulkload_state)
  File "/home/kave/workspace/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/bulkload/bulkloader_config.py", line 147, in dict_to_entity
    self.__run_import_transforms(input_dict, instance, bulkload_state_copy)
  File "/home/kave/workspace/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/bulkload/bulkloader_config.py", line 259, in __run_import_transforms
    value = self.__dict_to_prop(transform, input_dict, bulkload_state)
  File "/home/kave/workspace/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/bulkload/bulkloader_config.py", line 207, in __dict_to_prop
    value = transform.import_transform(value)
  File "/home/kave/workspace/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/bulkload/bulkloader_parser.py", line 111, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/kave/workspace/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/bulkload/transform.py", line 127, in generate_foreign_key_lambda
    value = int(value)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'em|xxxx@gmail.com'
[INFO    ] [WorkerThread-1] Backing off due to errors: 1.0 seconds
[INFO    ] An error occurred. Shutting down...
[ERROR   ] Error in WorkerThread-0: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'em|xxxx@gmail.com'
```

What do I have to change?
Many thanks

Comment: Looks like you might have some items where the I'd of key used in a reference property has been set explicitly, but for some reason it expects an into for the id.